Web Push via Azure Notification Hubs: JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.NotificationHubs.Contracts.LegacyModels.BrowserPushSubscription
I'm having a very difficult time making Web Push notifications work via Azure Notification Hubs.
Browser notifications support has been announced in March 2024, but it looks like any kind of proper availability is still missing, despite this and this pull requests waiting for several months to be merged.
I spent a decent amount of time trying some esoteric suggestions like this one, but I'm constantly failing at creating a new Installation for a Browser-based push notification target.
The error is:
Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.BadRequestException:  The provided request body is invalid. Error: The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.NotificationHubs.Contracts.LegacyModels.BrowserPushSubscription. Path: $.pushChannel | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 487.. TrackingId:dacca0ce-6af8-45b5-9ab5-ea1d1f78a57e,TimeStamp:9/21/2024 6:02:33 PM +00:00
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, String trackingId, HttpStatusCode[] successfulResponseStatuses, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, String trackingId, HttpStatusCode successfulResponseStatus, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.<>c__DisplayClass91_0.<<CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T](Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T](Func`2 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(Installation installation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

It looks like under the hood the Notification Hubs SDK is Serializing the BrowserPushSubscription instance a JSON string to be then saved into the PushChannel property.
Unfortunately, the Notification Hubs endpoint doesn't like it at all, because it's not capable of properly de-serializing it.
I tried to manually serialize it into different formats (IE: a common way to represent the browser subscription JSON is by grouping P256DH and Auth properties into a Keys subproperty), with no luck.
Is there anybody that got it working?
Thanks

SDK is causing serialization issues, it's best to bypass it for now and use the Azure Notification Hubs REST API directly.

I inspected the output with Fiddler and it was serialized as expected.
I also tried to bypass the PushChannel serialization and provide my own alternative data structures, with no luck.
Any detailed REST API documentation you could point me to? Thanks

Construct a manual JSON payload by yourself and send it via the Notification Hub REST API, bypassing the SDK.
JSON Payload :
{
  "installationId": "your-installation-id",
  "platform": "browser",
  "pushChannel": {
    "endpoint": "https://your-endpoint-url.com",
    "keys": {
      "p256dh": "your-p256dh-key",
      "auth": "your-auth-key"
    }
  },
  "tags": ["your-tag"]
}

Use REST API Directly:
curl -X PUT \
  https://<your-notification-hub-namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<your-hub-name>/installations/<your-installation-id>?api-version=2020-06 \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=<resource-uri>&sig=<signature>&se=<expiry>&skn=<policy-name>" \
  -d '{
    "installationId": "your-installation-id",
    "platform": "browser",
    "pushChannel": {
      "endpoint": "https://your-endpoint-url.com",
      "keys": {
        "p256dh": "your-p256dh-key",
        "auth": "your-auth-key"
      }
    },
    "tags": ["your-tag"]
  }'

Generate the Shared Access Signature (SAS), you can use Azure Portal or a script like this in C#
Code:
string resourceUri = "<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net";
string keyName = "<your-key-name>";
string key = "<your-primary-or-secondary-key>";

TimeSpan sinceEpoch = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
int expiry = Convert.ToInt32(sinceEpoch.TotalSeconds) + 3600; // 1 hour expiration

string stringToSign = WebUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri) + "\n" + expiry;
HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

string sasToken = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}",
    WebUtility.UrlEncode(resourceUri), WebUtility.UrlEncode(signature), expiry, keyName);

Console.WriteLine(sasToken);


Response (Success):
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Sep 2024 14:02:33 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
TrackingId: 3429bafa-212b-44ab-9b7e-caa3f217b7f5
x-ms-request-id: 7db24283-22c7-4e93-b865-9f6f063d5c7f
x-ms-version: 2020-02-09


Thank you for taking the time to elaborate this detailed answer.
I inspected the calls made by my server and they were looking exactly like your "Use REST API directly" section - in my many attempts, I also tried the same structure you're suggesting here, with "p256dh" and "p256dh" nested inside "keys".
I already developed my own alternative solution (using WebPush) that takes care of everything Notification Hubs does: I'm happy with it and I don't have time to try again, so I will mark your answer as Accepted and move on.
OTHER READERS BEWARE: I don't think this fixes my issue.

Based on the answer provided by @AndrewTheWild I realize I was still passing the PushChannel as a SERIALIZED STRING, instead of a nested object, so that is the issue with both pull requests I tried.

This was extremely helpful, thank you. Looking at the BrowserPushSubscription reference on github, I found that the keys property is no longer used. I had to send just endpoint, p256dh, and auth.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet/blob/87fca6b3d66ed2855dd6d304811a8045eb31c8f6/src/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/BrowserPushSubscription.cs#L11

I had a similar problem with the Azure NotificationHubs SDK. I found one suitable solution, I created my own SDK using Azure Notification Hub as the core.
The problem is inside the BrowserPushSubscription and BrowserInstallation classes. All libraries use Newtosoft Json, but BrowserPushSubscription uses System.Json, need to fix attributes. The next PushChannel is always a string, you need to change this property as an object and remove the serialization in the BrowserInstallation constructor.

That makes totally sense, thanks! Still wondering why Microsoft would announce the feature with such enthusiasm, just to leave it crippled for the next 6 months... I guess this and the accepted answer are both right and offer valid approaches to overcome the problem
